# know the parameter of common mode choke for power adapter

Tags: power-supply, inductor, electromagnetic, common-mode-choke

How to choose right common mode choke in my power supply design?
What are the parameters we have to consider during selection?

Thanks
Deep

Comment: You have to tell us why you think a choke is needed. Without that knowledge, why would you design one in? Also, where is it to be fitted?

Comment: It will use in universal AC input power supply. I wish to put it at AC mains connections (As I have seen such a reference circuits).

Comment: So what is it for - you need to understand that before you can choose one.

Answer (score 3):

You should first measure the conducted emissions of your device to the mains. Based on those readings you can identify which frequency components you wish to attenuate (referr to one of [these limits](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2012/jun/understanding-electromagnetic-compatibility-standards-for-switch-mode-power-supplies) to check what are the maximum emission levels).

Once you've identified what do you wish to attenuate I suggest you take a look at this:

[image]

Common Mode Chokes usually have this graph in the datasheet:

[image]

In its common configuration (black line in this case) you'll see if it will propperly attenuate your target frequencies. If you want to attenuate outside of the reach of the CM Choke, take a look at the filter structure picture before, you'll identify which elements tend to affect which frequencies.